# Shorten a string in JTabel when cell is too small

Tags: java, string, cell

When a cell is too small to display the whole string, it shortens the end by adding '...'. For instance: "This is a string" becomes "This is..."
Is there a way to shorten it at the beginning? "...a string".

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTable` by default uses a `JLabel` as its rendering component, so basically you need to tell that label how to shorten your string. You can do that by implementing a custom `TableCellRenderer`. Perhaps you can use the [Left Dot Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/) as a starting point and extend it, if it does not exactly suits your needs.